# VMware error - This host does not support Intel VT-x

Tags: vmware

I am trying to get VMware 14 working on an HP Compaq Presario CQ56-201SQ Laptop and I'm getting the error:

```
This host does not support Intel VT-x.
This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization.
Module 'CPUIDEarly' power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

I checked my BIOS and I didn't see any "Virtual Technology" option to enable.

I was trying to update my BIOS using Linux by creating a FreeDOS USB and adding the .exe file on it.

When I tried to execute it, I got the error:

```
This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

BIOS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WRmq.jpg

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Thank you!!

Comment: Contact the vendor

Comment: The [HP Compaq Presario CQ56-201SQ](https://icecat.in/en/p/hp/lc696ea/compaq-presario-notebooks-CQ56-201SQ-7972019.html) uses an Intel Celeron T3500 64-bit processor, which [does not support VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#%22Penryn-3M%22_(45_nm)) technology.